# What are the differences between declaring a KnockoutJS model with self-invoking function?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I've seen view models being declared as functions.  I'm guessing this is because it makes it easier to refer back to other functions and variables inside the closure?  If it was a simple key/value object you couldn't use 'this' to refer to other variables/functions.

However, there are 2 ways of declaring the model using a function.

```
var vm1 = function () {
     this.mydata = ko.observable(null)
}

ko.applyBindings(new vm1());
```

And then also using a self-invoking function:

```
var vm2 = function () {
     this.mydata = ko.observable(null)
}();

ko.applyBindings(vm2);
```

What is the difference between the 2 approaches?  What I am finding is that using the 2nd approach causes problems because I'm not sure if KO can 'see' the properties inside vm2 as they are private.  But then how how are the properties in vm1 visible?

I'm also wondering if the 'revealing-module' pattern is compatible with KO view models and whether I should use this instead?

Comment: Oh wait a minute, does this.* effectively create public properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In you first example you are declaring an new instance of vm1 object and the this refer to the vm1 instance

In the second example the this refer to the window object and not to the instance of vm2

Then yes to answer to your own comment the second example will only create a property called mydata in the window object.